# re render a django view with change in context after POST request

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to change content of a table by applying filters in a django template but I am unable to re render the same page again with change in context. I don't want to use javascript or class based views so could you please suggest a way to do it in django function based view. Below is sample code

```
def Endtoendtrackerview(request,*args,**kwargs):

    def executefunction(orderobj,baseobj):
        'somecode which returns a context dictionary
        return context

    if request.method = POST:
        'some code
        orderobj = OrderModel.objects.filter(status = True)
        baseobj = BaseModel.objects.filter(process = process)
        context = executefunction(orderobj,baseobj)
        return render(request, "app/end_to_end_tracker.html",context)
    orderobj = OrderModel.objects.all()
    baseobj = BaseModel.objects.all()
    context = executefunction(orderobj,baseobj)
    return render(request, "app/end_to_end_tracker.html",context)
```

update :
I am trying to update content of an HTML table based on dropdown filters in the template 'end_to_end_tracker.html' . The user will select a value from dropdown filter and submit a post request. The table needs to render the updated data.

Comment: IT is not entirely clear to me *what* you aim to achieve, and what is not working. So when exactly should the template be rerendered and how?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem - I have updated the question. I hope it is clear now. Currently the page is not reloading after a post request and hence the data is not updating

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to update the DOM after a user request. This is HTMX library job. My advice is to change your strategy and use HTMX. You send the ajax request to the server and receive HTML code in the response. The mechanism is to update the page without refreshing. You don't write a single line of JS.
Studying HTMX with django is time well spent.
If you are interested in learning more, find the link below.

[The HTMX official page](https://htmx.org/)

Comment: You understood the question right and this is helpful but the reason I didn't want to use JS was that I am a beginner and I  don't want to get into learning anything else other than Django at the moment. I am okay with the page being reloaded to render the updated content